# Angular Controller and modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a customized modal, that must be placed in the `html` page.

it has a controller as follows

```
    <html ng-app="app" ng-controller="htmlCtrl">

    <body ng-class = "{'modal' : showAddDoctor == true }">
.....
<ng-view></ng-view>
.....
<div id="modal">
<button ng-click="closemodal()"></button> <!--- not working ---->
</div>
```

In the htmlCtrl i have two `$on` events as follows

```
    $scope.$on("ShowModal",function(event){
        $scope.ShowModal = true;
    });
    $scope.$on("HideModal", function(event) {
        $scope.ShowModal = false;
    });
```

Now in the controller in one of the views i `$emit`

`$scope.$emit("ShowModal);`

That works perfectly.

Now back to the `htmlCtrl` i try calling the `closeModal()` so that i can `$scope.$emit("HideModal")`; 
but it does not work.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Rather than emiting events on function calls can you try ng-controller==htmlCtrl as vm" then do ng-click="vm.ShowModal = false"

Comment: you mean ng-controller=htmlCtrl as vm on the <div id="modal"> ?

Comment: no, leave it where it is but alias it as vm then replace closemodal() with vm.ShowModal = false

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y038 - If you plan on doing much angular development I highly recommend following this style guide. This link is the example on using the ng-controller="controllername as vm" practice

Comment: oh sorry about that i got it and yes it works but what if i want to call a function to so other things like save the modal form data

Comment: I am following that style guide and i am using typescript indeed

Comment: You can do vm.closeAndSave() and then in the function you would do the $scope.ShowModal = false and whatever else you need. no need to emit an event though

Comment: Does this plunker help? http://plnkr.co/edit/kT1AYe2Y2bUUS7UPQKzy?p=preview

Comment: @matthewdaniel yup all is good thanks mate

Comment: @Kilmazing no it was a little far from what i wanted but thanks